# SparkSession: using the SQL API to query Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Python, using `SparkSession` I can load a Cassandra keyspace and *table* like:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("TestApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

cassandra = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
df = cassandra.load(keyspace="testdb", table="test")

df.collect()
```

How can I use the SQL API instead? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM testdb.test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try register temp table in Spark and run queries against it like in a following snippet:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table")
```